# How to detect version of an iOS device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, version

Below is my code try to detect the version number of a device below 7.9. On my friend 's phone which have IOS 7.1.1 still going to the else-statement instead going to the if-statement.

```
NSString* minimumVersionString = @"7.9";
NSComparisonResult versionComparison = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:minimumVersionString options:NSNumericSearch];

if (versionComparison == NSOrderedSame || versionComparison == NSOrderedAscending)
{

}
else {
     [self popoverCategoryWithAlertController];
}
```

I would have thought if a device which has IOS 7.1.2 or lower will be executed this if-statement :

```
if (versionComparison == NSOrderedSame || versionComparison == NSOrderedAscending)
```

But it was not.. Am I use a wrong way to check the device IOS version

I even do this but same result:

```
if ([NSProcessInfo instanceMethodForSelector:@selector(isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:)]) {
    if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:versions])
        [self popoverCategoryWithAlertController];
    else   {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to detect the iOS version? Because it is much better to detect if a method exists of check the foundation version.

Just do something like:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
    [self presentViewController:errorView animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:errorView animated:YES];
}
```

Or if you need :

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
     // Load resources for iOS 7.1.* or earlier
} else {
    // Load resources for iOS 8 or later
}
```

Comment: Then please explain what you are trying to detect exactly and why. Also post you code and what is not work. Include what you think should happen and what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
NSString* minimumVersionString = @"7.9";
NSComparisonResult versionComparison = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:minimumVersionString options:NSNumericSearch];

if (versionComparison != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    //do some iOS 7.9 or greater stuff
}
else {

}
```

Comment: Just turning the if around just not matter, this is exactly the same a above just turned around,. Also you should never use this, use `respondsToSelector:` or `NSFoundationVersionNumber`.

Comment: @rckoenes YES!! use of `NSFoundationVersionNumber` is good programming practices.